# Best way to get a result from a called java program?

Tags: java, javascript, xcode, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I am calling a external java program within my javascript test case, with `performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout` and it works perfectly.

Now in the javascript testcase I need the result of the called program for the next test step.

I could write the result within java into a file and could read the result in javascript, but this could not be the smartest way (or is it ?).

I have found another approach, with using environment variables, which sounded good, but I have not been able to get it work.

How do you get around with something like this ?

I would appreciate some examples within your answers.

*** EDIT ***

The result of `performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout` is not only needed in the calling test case, but also in the following ones.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but is there any reason you couldn't just return the response as the return type from the java method, then have that bubble up to your JS?

Comment: I forgot to tell, the result of the `performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout` is also needed in the next test cases